# Why are quest items not showing up in the Spectre terminal?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There are at least two quests where I'm supposed to buy something from Spectre reqs and they don't show up in the terminal.

I just got finished with *N7: Cerberus Abductions* and I'm trying to finish the *Benning: Evidence* quest. The guide I'm looking at says the quest must be completed before completing *Priority: Tuchaunka*, which is the next quest I have available. Nothing aside from guns is showing up in Spectre reqs at the moment. Does anybody know how I can get around this, or if there's an additional requirement I need to fulfill?

EDIT: Turns out if you find his dogtags while on the N7: Cerberus Abductions quest, you just give them to his father to finish the quest.

Comment: where is the specter terminal?

Comment: @Shaun on the Citadel, Embassies district.

Answer (score 1):

Some quest items will only appear in the Requisition Office after you have failed to collect them during the mission they were in.